# Django - filter Products in Category by Brands and other characteristics

Tags: django

I am trying to create an online store. Made categories, products are filtered correctly by category. Now I’m trying to filter products in categories by brand and other attributes. But it does not work.

```
#Models
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    category = TreeForeignKey('Category', related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey('Vendor', related_name='vendors', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

#urls
urlpatterns = [
    path('catalog/<slug:slug>/', views.category_catalog, name='category_catalog')
]

#views
def category_catalog(request, slug=None):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    breadcrumbs = Category.get_ancestors(category, include_self=True)
    # cat = Product.objects.filter(category__in=Category.objects.get(id=category.id).get_descendants())

if category.get_level() <= 1:
    cat = category.get_descendants().order_by('tree_id', 'id', 'name')

    return render(request, 'shop/category_catalog.html', {'category': category,
                                                          'cat': cat,
                                                          'menu': menu(request),
                                                          'breadcrumbs': breadcrumbs})
if category.get_level() >= 2:
    list_pro = Product.objects.filter(category__in=Category.objects.get(id=category.id)\
                                           .get_descendants(include_self=True)) \
                                           .annotate(min_price=Min('prices__price'))

    vendors_ids = list_pro.values_list('vendor_id', flat=True).order_by().distinct()
    vendors = Vendor.objects.filter(id__in=vendors_ids)
    filter = BrandFilter(queryset=Vendor.objects.all())

    print(filter)
    print(vendors)
    products_list = helpers.pg_records(request, list_pro, 12)
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    cat = category.get_descendants(include_self=True).order_by('tree_id', 'id', 'name')
    last_node = category.get_siblings(include_self=True)

    return render(request, 'shop/category_product_list.html', {'products_list': products_list,
                                                               'category': category,
                                                               'vendors': vendors,
                                                               'cat': cat,
                                                               'last_node': last_node,
                                                               'menu': menu(request),
                                                               'breadcrumbs': breadcrumbs,
                                                               'filter': filter,
                                                               })
```

How can I implement this idea?

Comment: Are you using some third party app with Django?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution via Forms! It works, but I'm still experimenting. My solution!

```
#Forms
class BrandForms(forms.Form):
    brand = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Vendor.objects.none())
```

## View

```
filter_brand = BrandForms(request.GET)
    if filter_brand.is_valid():
        if filter_brand.cleaned_data['brand']:
            print(filter_brand.cleaned_data['brand'])
            list_pro = Product.objects.filter(category__in=Category.objects.get(id=category.id)\
                                               .get_descendants(include_self=True)) \
                                               .annotate(min_price=Min('prices__price'))\
                                               .filter(vendor_id__in=filter_brand.cleaned_data['brand'])
```